# How do I `View()` an in-memory table in R with dbplyr? without SQL queries

Tags: r, r-dbi, dbplyr

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars)

mtcars2 <- tbl(con, "mtcars")
mtcars2
#> # Source:   table<mtcars> [?? x 11]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.25.3 [:memory:]
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # … with more rows
```

How do I view a table that is in memory in R? I'm utilizing DBI and dbplyr packages. I'm looking for the spreadsheet view in R Studio that pops up when you issue a command such as `View(mtcars)`. And I really want to only view the first 10 or 20 rows of a table. A lot of the SQL tables I work with are millions of rows, hundreds of columns, and I don't want all that data to display.

Things just seem different *enough* going from dplyr to dbplyr to slightly confuse me. And if you're wondering why I'm not happy with the console view presented above, because it usually cuts off at about a dozen variables, or however wide your console is. I need to browse all variables (columns), even when my tables are hundreds of columns wide.

```
# Doesn't really work
mtcars2 %>% View()
```

Let me also mention I want to avoid having to use direct SQL queries in the answer, if it's even possible. I'm somewhat open to utilizing the `collect()` function, but it seems very slow when the tables are around size 250K+ rows, 100+ columns.

Comment: you need to `collect` it: `mtcars2 %>% collect %>% View` should give what you want

Comment: @DiceboyT that works but tends to be very slow with large tables. Any way around this other than filtering() which I don't always have the luxury of doing? I've tried to `slice()` and also `mutate()` a `rn = row_number()` and filter that way, but it doesn't seem to work on my TeraData SQL tables.

Comment: Use `head`, it should be pretty fast: `tbl %>% head(10) %>% collect %>% View`

Comment: @DiceboyT that works great and does what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DiceboyT pointed out the solution

```
mtcars2 %>% head(10) %>% collect() %>% View()
```